# Unable to get current location using GPS with GoogleApiClient

Tags: java, android, gps

I am trying to make a button work in my application that will collect the latitude and longitude of the device when the user clicks it. The button works fine, yet it is not calling the class method from my GPSHelper class. Any help with this would be appreciated. I am testing and trying this out on my actual device and not an emulator if that helps any. Thanks for any help.

Here is my GPSHelper class where I am placing all the permissions checks and code for the GPS usage.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;


/**
 * This class takes care of capturing the location of the device.
 */

public class GPSHelper extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{

    private final Context mContext;
    boolean isGpsEnabled = false;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    double mLatitude;
    double mLongitude;

    public GPSHelper(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        isGpsEnabled = mGoogleApiClient.isConnected();

        if (isGpsEnabled){
            mLatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            mLongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(mLatitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(mLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }

        return mLastLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.mContext, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) this.mContext,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 10);
            }
        } else {
            if (mLastLocation == null){
                mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                getLocation();
            }else {
                getLocation();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case 10:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    getLocation();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Action Canceled\nGPS Is Required",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is the activity where I am trying to call the `getLocation()` class method with an instance of the `GPSHelper` class.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.bigdaddy.as_built_weldmapper.utilities.BendHelper;
import com.example.bigdaddy.as_built_weldmapper.utilities.GPSHelper;

public class SagActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener,
        MajorButtonFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Communicator{

    /* Using this to insert into the Bend Direction field. */
    public static String SAG_DIRECTION = "SAG";

    /* This spinner holds the bend types */
    Spinner mSagBendTypesSpinner;

    /* Using this string to collect what was selected for the spinner type */
    private String mBendTypeSpinnerVal;

    /* All the EditText for the Activity */
    private EditText mSagGpsShotEt;
    private EditText mSagExistingGpsEt;
    private EditText mSagCoverEt;
    private EditText mSagDegreeEt;
    private EditText mSagDistanceFromEt;
    private EditText mSagNotesEt;
    private EditText mSagOccupyIdEt;
    private EditText mSagStationNumEt;

    public GPSHelper mGPSHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sag);
        mGPSHelper = new GPSHelper(SagActivity.this);

        /* checking if the MajorButtonFragment is null */
        if (findViewById(R.id.majorButtonFragment) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
        }

        /* Referencing the spinner and setting the itemsSelectedListener */
        mSagBendTypesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bend_types_spinner);
        mSagBendTypesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);
        /* Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout */
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.bend_types_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        /* Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears */
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        /* Apply the adapter to the spinner */
        mSagBendTypesSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        /* Referencing and calling all the EditText for the Activity */
        mSagGpsShotEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextGpsShotForSag);
        mSagExistingGpsEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextExistGradeForSag);
        mSagCoverEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextCoverForSag);
        mSagDegreeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextDegreeForSag);
        mSagDistanceFromEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextDistanceFromForSag);
        mSagNotesEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextNotesForSagActivity);
        mSagOccupyIdEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextJointIdSagActivity);
        mSagStationNumEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextStationNumSagActivity);
    } /*onCreate() ends here.*/

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        mBendTypeSpinnerVal = mSagBendTypesSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void exitBtnRespond() {

    }

    /**
     * This overridden method comes from the Communicator Interface and is used globally in all
     * Activities that implement it to Store (write) a transaction to the database.
     * The utility class saveAndInsertBend() method is invoked here.
     */
    @Override
    public void storeBtnRespond() {
        BendHelper.saveAndInsertBend(SagActivity.this, SAG_DIRECTION, mBendTypeSpinnerVal, mSagStationNumEt,
                mSagOccupyIdEt, mSagDegreeEt, mSagDistanceFromEt, mSagGpsShotEt, mSagExistingGpsEt,
                mSagCoverEt, mSagNotesEt);
    }

    @Override
    public void mapItBtnRespond() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MapItBtn clicked in SagActivity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mGPSHelper.getLocation();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

The Overridden `mapItBtnRespond()` method comes from a `Fragment` class I have that contains my buttons and it does work. The `Toast` message displays every time I click the button but no permissions are asked for on nothing. Where am I going wrong with all of this?

Also here is the `Manifest` file with the permissions in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.bigdaddy.as_built_weldmapper">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> '-->
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".WeldActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SagActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".OverbendActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LtPiActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RtPiActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CmboObRtActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ComboObLtActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ComboSagRtActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ComboSagLtActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i am getting continues location updates

**MyLocation.java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
  * Created by Rana Shahzaib on 1/9/2017.
  */

public class MyLocation {
Context context;

MyLocation(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

Timer timer1;
LocationManager lm;
LocationResult locationResult;
boolean gps_enabled = false;
boolean network_enabled = false;

public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result) {
    //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
    locationResult = result;
    if (lm == null)
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    try {
        network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    //Toast.makeText(context, gps_enabled+" "+network_enabled,     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    }
    if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
        return false;
    if (gps_enabled)
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
    if (network_enabled)
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
    timer1 = new Timer();


    timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 10000);
    return true;
}

LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        timer1.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
};

LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        timer1.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
};

class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
    @Override

    public void run() {

        //Context context = getClass().getgetApplicationContext();
        Location net_loc = null, gps_loc = null;
        if (gps_enabled)
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
        gps_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(network_enabled)
            net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        //if there are both values use the latest one
        if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
            if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
            else
                locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
            return;
        }

        if(gps_loc!=null){
            locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
            return;
        }
        if(net_loc!=null){
            locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
            return;
        }
        locationResult.gotLocation(null);
    }
}

public static abstract class LocationResult{
    public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
}}
```

And here i am getting location

```
MyLocation mLocation = new MyLocation(this);
mLocation.getLocation(this, new MyLocation.LocationResult() {

    @Override
    public void gotLocation(Location location) {
        //Your Logic
    }
});
```